# NaN means in image resize in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, resize

What this code mean??
this code is written in matlab.

```
 citra=imresize(citra,[400 NaN]);
```

i just know that the image (citra) is resize into 400. But, what about Nan?
What that's mean?

Answer (score 3):

Read the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html

> Either numrows or numcols may be NaN, in which case imresize computes
>   the number of rows or columns automatically to preserve the image
>   aspect ratio.

Comment: i still cannot understand. If i changed the NaN with other number, the program will result an error. But if i use NaN the result is right.

Comment: I suspect imresize is required to maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: It is not. You can resize it to any arbitrary size. What are the dimensions of the original image and are you trying to resize it to?

Answer (score 2):

Using `Nan` in `imresize` keeps the proportions of your original image. If you set `x` to be 400 then y is modified proportionnally. It is the equivalent of binding the `x` or `y`in photoshop (or other image editor) for example.

[image]